# Minimizer of Perturbed Mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose that $X \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a complete probability space. I know that the minimizer of 
$$
\inf_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}\left[
(r-X)^2
\right],
$$
is the mean of $X$.  My question, is how could we solve for the minimizer of $$
\inf_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}\left[
(r-X)^2
\right]-r?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin with the ansatz that $\mathbb{E}[(r-X)^2]$ is differentiable as a function of $r$ (or show it), then computing the gradient and setting it to $0$, we see that
$$
\begin{aligned}
0=&\nabla \mathbb{E}[(r-X)^2] - r = \mathbb{E}[2(r-X)]-1\\
r & = \mathbb{E}[X]+\frac1{2} = \mu_X + \frac1{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Just make sure that the ansatz works in general; I'll leave that part to you :)

Comment: Cool, I'll look up the detail and check.  Thanks as always @AIM_BLB

Comment: My pleasure @N00ber :)